# what is the best way to convert html to RTF in java by opensource java library

Tags: java

converting html to rtf in java by java swing not helping much,so looking for opensource library

Comment: Why does your question body say "word doc" but your title says RTF?

Comment: i have a two options to do directly converting html to word doc or converting html to rtf then save it as word doc.mistakenly i have added word doc in body.i corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your title you just need to get RTF from HTML page.
So for that you can use PD4ML library.
add this to your pom first

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.pd4ml</groupId>
      <artifactId>pd4ml</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Example

```
public class Converter {
protected Dimension format = PD4Constants.A4;
protected boolean landscapeValue = false;
protected int topValue = 10;
protected int leftValue = 10;
protected int rightValue = 10;
protected int bottomValue = 10;
protected String unitsValue = "mm";
protected String proxyHost = "";
protected int proxyPort = 0;
protected int userSpaceWidth = 780;

private void runConverter(String urlstring, File output) throws IOException {
    if (urlstring.length() > 0) {
        if (!urlstring.startsWith("http://") && !urlstring.startsWith("file:")) {
            urlstring = "http://" + urlstring;
        }
        java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(output);
        if (proxyHost != null && proxyHost.length() != 0 && proxyPort != 0) {
            System.getProperties().setProperty("proxySet", "true");
            System.getProperties().setProperty("proxyHost", proxyHost);
            System.getProperties().setProperty("proxyPort", "" + proxyPort);
        }
        PD4ML pd4ml = new PD4ML();
        try {
            pd4ml.setPageSize(landscapeValue ? pd4ml.changePageOrientation(format) : format);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (unitsValue.equals("mm")) {
            pd4ml.setPageInsetsMM(new Insets(topValue, leftValue, bottomValue, rightValue));
        } else {
            pd4ml.setPageInsets(new Insets(topValue, leftValue, bottomValue, rightValue));
        }
        pd4ml.setHtmlWidth(userSpaceWidth);
        pd4ml.render(urlstring, fos);
    }
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: is PD4ML is open source?can i embedded this with my java code because other library is not allowed me to use.

Comment: definitely you can use this dependency. just try with sample project first.